# Invoke existing functions only in variadic templated class

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I have a variadic templated class and I want to invoke a function when and only when the template class has the function.

What I have so far is as below.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
constexpr std::false_type hasFooHelper(long);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto hasFooHelper(int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().foo(), std::true_type{} );

template <typename T>
using has_foo = decltype( hasFooHelper<T>(0) );

class WithFoo
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        printf("%s\n", __func__);
    }
};

template <class... T>
class myclass
{
public:
    void invokeFoo()
    {
        if constexpr((has_foo<T>() && ...))
        {
            (T().foo(), ...);
        }
    } 
};

int main()
{
    myclass<WithFoo> a;
    myclass<int> b;
    myclass<WithFoo, int> c;

    a.invokeFoo(); // Invokes WithFoo::foo()
    b.invokeFoo(); // Do nothing
    c.invokeFoo(); // Do nothing, how to make this invoke WithFoo::foo()?
    return 0;
}
```

It works expected for `myclass<WithFoo>` and `myclass<int>`, but for `myclass<WithFoo, int>`, it will do nothing.

How to make `myclass<WithFoo, int>` to invoke `WithFoo::foo()` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if constexpr((has_foo<T>() && ...))
{
    (T().foo(), ...);
}
```

checks if *every* `T` has a `foo()`, and then invokes `foo()` on *every* `T`.

What you apparently want is, for each `T`, conditionally invoke it. You can do that by wrapping this in a lambda for a specific type:

```
auto maybe_foo = [](auto x){
    if constexpr (has_foo<decltype(x)>()) {
        x.foo();
    }
};
```

And then invoke that lambda on every type:

```
(maybe_foo(T()), ...);
```

---

That's the simplest solution, probably. The downside is that you create a bunch of `T()`s even if you can't `.foo()` them. You can get around that by wrapping the `T`s in a tag type:

```
template <typename T> struct type_t { using type = T; };

auto maybe_foo = [](auto x){
    using T = typename decltype(x)::type;
    if constexpr (has_foo<T>()) {
        T().foo();
    }
};
(maybe_foo(type_t<T>()), ...);
```

---

Separately from all of that, use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) in C++17 instead of rolling your own version of it. It'll be a lot easier:

```
template <typename T> using foo_type_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().foo());
template <typename T> using has_foo = is_detected<foo_type_t, T>;
```

Comment: `is_detected` is new to me, it looks like it's in `<experimental/type_traits>`, is it part of C++17 officially?

Comment: @Mine It's not in C++17, but you should use it anyway.